# How can I get the correct position of a button? (Java, JButton)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have created a simple frame with a panel, that has a grid layout manager. When I create two custom buttons with overwritten paintComponent(g: Graphics) method then the background of one button is painted wrong.

I guess this is due to the fact that the position is always x=0, y=0. How can I fix that?

Button code:

```
public class JRoundedButton extends JButton {

private int arcRadius;

public JRoundedButton(String label, int arcRadius) {
    super(label);
    this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    this.arcRadius = arcRadius;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        //super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Draw button background
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRoundRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, arcRadius, arcRadius);

        //Draw font
        this.paintText(graphics);
    }
}


protected final void paintText(@NotNull Graphics2D g) {
    //Draw font
    g.setColor(getForeground());
    if (this.getFont() != null && this.getText() != null) {
        FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        g.setColor(this.getForeground());
        g.drawString(this.getText(), ((this.getWidth() / 2) - (fm.stringWidth(this.getText()) / 2)),
                ((this.getHeight() / 2) + fm.getMaxDescent()));
    }
}
```

And here is the frame creation code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Buttontest");
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    contentPanel.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    contentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 20));

    JRoundedButton button1 = new JRoundedButton("Rounded Button", 40);
    button1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    button1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    JRoundedButton button2 = new JRoundedButton("Rounded Button 2", 40);
    button2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    button2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    contentPanel.add(button1);
    contentPanel.add(button2);

    frame.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

If I execute the button, the upper one appears as expected, but the lower one does not show the black background. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On quick glance, I note that this is wrong:

```
graphics.fillRoundRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, arcRadius, arcRadius);
```

Understand that both `getX()` and `getY()` return the component's position ***relative to its parent component***, usually a JPanel that your button sits in, but this is not where you should be drawing. Rather the drawing should be in a location ***relative to the button itself***.

So this will probably work better:

```
graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, arcRadius, arcRadius);
```

Comment: You are soo awesome! This took me like days and I didn't notice that. Thank you for your answer! Have a good one ;)